# How do I uninstall Afloat in Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, osx-lion

I have tried [Afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/) for windows management in my Mac (OS X Lion), but I do not find it very useful. Would anybody know how I can uninstall it, please?

The official website has no guide on uninstalling it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like it's a SIMBL plugin, which means you just need to move it out of

```
/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins
```

or

```
~/Library/Application Support/SIMBL/Plugins
```

You might also want to uninstall SIMBL as well.

Most of the Mac OS X community, especially the developer community, look down upon anything that uses SIMBL, APE (Unsanity's Application Enhancer, "haxies"), or other so-called "Input Manager hacks" because they alter the runtime environment of other apps in unapproved, unpredictable ways, and thus can cause other applications to crash.

Comment: If I copy the Afloat.bundle file from one Mac to another, will that be enough to copy Afloat between them? (since the installer is no longer available)

Answer (score 4):

For Leopard:

> Uninstalling Afloat & PlugSuit on Leopard.
>
> To uninstall Afloat and PlugSuit on Mac OS X 10.5 “Leopard”, use the
>   Afloat 2 Installer application you used to install Afloat on your
>   computer. These instructions only apply to Mac OS X 10.5 “Leopard”. If
>   you installed the Afloat Pack for Snow Leopard, see instead
>   Uninstalling the Afloat Pack for Snow Leopard.
>
> Removing Afloat & PlugSuit To remove: Open the Afloat 2 Installer
>   application you used to install Afloat. If you don't have it anymore,
>   you can redownload the Afloat installer for Leopard at any time. In
>   the lower-left corner of the installer's window, click on Remove, then
>   Remove Afloat & PlugSuit. The installer will then remove the software.

For Snow Leopard (& Lion / Mountain Lion):

> Uninstalling the Afloat Pack for Snow Leopard.
>
> Afloat Pack for Snow Leopard includes Afloat 2.2 and SIMBL. To remove
>   each, follow these steps: Removing Afloat In the Finder, choose Go >
>   Home from the menu. Open the following folders: Library > Application
>   Support > SIMBL > Plugins Move the Afloat icon to the trash. You might
>   need to log out and log back in to be able to empty the Trash.
>   Removing SIMBL Download the latest SIMBL for Snow Leopard distribution
>   at the SIMBL web site. Use the SIMBL Uninstaller application in the
>   distribution to remove SIMBL. Please note: This may stop other system
>   extenders from working. Make sure you're not using other system
>   extenders before you remove SIMBL.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstalling SIMBL the hard way (remove all residue) do the following:

`locate SIMBL | sudo xargs rm -rf`

Comment: After using this command (and entered my password), I have no error, but files are still here. That's so weird.

Comment: I think it's related to OS X 10.11 SIP thing...

Comment: That thing might have some interesting info about how to delete SIMBL on OS X (you need to disable SIP for a while) https://josephkotzker.wordpress.com/2016/02/19/install-working-simbl-framework-on-os-x-10-11-el-capitan/

Comment: I explained how to uninstall based on your command here http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/153742/is-it-safe-to-uninstall-simbl-agent-on-yosemite/229757#229757